# how to implement OCI(Open Catalogue Interface) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sap-srm

Open Catalog Interface In SAP

1. I am trying to implement URL for SAP to connect my product catalog to SAP SRM.
2. How should I data in response to this URL
3. Which method is called by SRM server (GET/POST) ?
4. And how to autheticate userId and password at our side.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to create open catalog interface

1. you have to create client route instead of server route
2. no need of response as it is client route data is sent from html
3. No method is called
4. User-Id and password are sent as plain text parameters in call URL